# Where does the ribbon ending in sticky metallic tape attach in a laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I bought a used laptop, but needed to install a new hard drive.

Inside the laptop there is a single large ribbon which forks into two ribbons. The first fork ends in ~1.5 inch plug with two sets of pins. One part has 15 pins, the other part 7. I easily found where this plugs into the hard drive.

The other fork ends in a 1 inch^2 piece of sticky metallic tape:

```
                  [] <------------------ small chip
                  ||
            |=====//
<--- laptop |=================[:] <----- 7 pins
            |=================[:] }
            |=================[:] }
            |=================[:] } <--- 15 pins
            |=================[:] }
            |=================[:] }
            |
            |=======\\
                    ||
                    ||
                    -- <---------------- small connector
                    ||                   (difficult to pull apart)
                ____||____
                |        |
                |        | <------------ metallic tape
                |        |
                |________|
```

I searched many hard drive install how-to guides and cannot find anything mentioning this. Also, I found pictures of SATA ribbon cables on eBay, but none have this metallic square. Where does this ribbon with the metallic tape go?

Comment: What is the laptop make and model? Most laptops have a service manual which can usually be found on the manufacturers website ...

Comment: It is an Itronix GoBook XR-1. The support Web sites do not offer a complete and detailed manual, only documents showing the outside parts. In the specs, they list a "hard drive heater", that heats the drives at low temperatures of 5 degrees F and below. If that is what this is, what part of the drive needs heating?

Comment: I found a [product review](http://www.gd-itronix.com/upload/pdf/laptop_eprint_previous2.pdf) saying the heater "heats the area around the
axis, to warm up the grease". Is that part the round metal part on the back of the drive? Is that circle on the hard drive safe to touch?

Comment: Does this video help? [hard drive replacement on the General Dynamics GoBook XR-1 Itronix IX-270](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alf_fMjdEuc)

Comment: Thanks! My workplace does not let me view the link, but I will check some hours later.